# Sending email in kivy is not working

Tags: android, python, email

I have written code below and save it as main.py and then by buildozer i made apk file and deploy in my phone but it crashes....why?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import smtplib
fromaddr = "nisargjani20996@gmail.com"
toaddrs  = "nisargjani20996@gmail.com"
msg = "Why,Oh why!"
username = "myfrien@gmail.com"
password = "password"
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')

def callback(instance):     
     server.starttls()
     server.login(username,password)    
     server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
     server.quit()

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        b=Button(text='press me')
        b.bind(on_press=callback)
        return b    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Please correct your quote character

Comment: I am new at this forum..so i mistacally do thta...but bro please can you solve this above script...its so important for me...i can't understand why it crashes every time

Comment: `msg = "Why,Oh why!'` Is the single quote at the end of this statement a typo?

Comment: it was the mistake when i was posting this...this is not error that is crashing app

Comment: Will anyone please help me

Comment: Will someone please help me with this script

Answer (score 0):

Try set android.permissions = INTERNET in buildozer.spec

Comment: "Try..." and no explanation... Could you phrase more assertively?